# Can a ReactJs component render 2 table cells

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

We have a component that may render two cells in a table.  This is showing an amount followed by a type (like USD, CNY, etc..).  The table is used because it allows the right justification of the number and the left justification of the denomination making it much easier to read.  The column header is easy to add using `colSpan="2"`.  The problem is, this is hit or miss.  I believe the browser is filtering out the inner `</td><td>`.  If I render `</td><td>_` the `td` elements will not appear in the dom but the `_` will.  This is probably because the we are forced to return a single html element from render so we use `<span>`.  This breaks the HTML validity of the table by rendering it like this: `<tr><td><span>123.45</td><td>USD</span></td> .... </tr>` (where the following component renders the center part: `<span>123.45</td><td>USD</span>`).

So, we are kind of stuck with tables as far as I know.  Is their an easy way to create a 2 cell React.Component without breaking the HTML table format?

```
render() {
  return (
    <span>
      {this.props.amount}
      <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.element_separator}} />
      {this.props.asset.symbol}
    </span>
  )
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use two `div`s and let them float with css?

Comment: I believe I would need to get into fixed column size.  (EDIT, remember the header spans two columns). The table is nice because it can grow where needed and keep everything aligned.  The divs and css is probably the way to do if a simple solution can't be found here.

Comment: Maybe this project might be useful: [FixedDataTable](https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/)

Comment: You need to have the component building the `tr` handle the `td` creation in this case rather than delegating the responsibility to a single component.